# iOS: Passing a string parameter to a function, but it's NULL on the other end?

Tags: ios, objective-c, php-ziparchive

I'm working on an iPad app and I'm using ZipArchive to unzip files that I download. However, when I try to open the files, I find that the open method thinks I passed in a nil parameter.

```
NSString* filepath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"help_me.zip" ofType:@"zip"] copy];
ZipArchive* zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath Password:@"XYZ"];
```

In the 'UnzipOpenFile' method, the debugger says that 'filePath' is nil. I'm not sure why this happens. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"help_me.zip" ofType:@"zip"]
```

you have specified the file extension *twice*, so that will return `nil`
(unless your file is called "help_me.zip.zip").
It should be

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"help_me" ofType:@"zip"]
```

Btw., there is no need to `copy` the file path.

Comment: This is the right answer. Thank you. I will accept the answer in 9 minutes (per Stack's rules).